# Make app-specific .css file for gtk theme

Tags: themes, kde, gtk

I have conflict problems with using dark theme and a KDE application (kile). As you can see from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNDxN.png), the log area (at the bottom) is black on gray, which is very annoying to read.

I know one can make .css files for specific applications in `/usr/share/themes/<themename>/gtk-3.0/apps`, but I am completely lost at where to start.

Can I get a quick rundown on how a gtk application (such as kile) will call stuff in the .css file of it's name?

Comment: Is `kile` really a gtk app? The depends I see in`apt-cache show kile` indicate that it is a `qt` app.

Comment: But by changing stuff in the gtk-3.0 and 2.0 (installing new themes and the like), stuff in Kile changes. From what I understand, the editor itself in kile is Kate, but the 'stuff around the editor', such as the message log seem to be affected by changes in the gtk folders.

Comment: In any case, if it is a qt app, how do I change how things are drawn?

Comment: Then can you please clarify if changes in gtk2 **or** gtk3 folders influence the appearance? It should be one or the other.

Comment: Re. how things are drawn in a qt app, the closest I can think of is `qt4-qtconfig`. It's in "Universe". `apt-cache show qt4-qtconfig` tells us that the _Qt 4 configuration tool ... allows end users to configure the look and behavior of any Qt 4 application._

Comment: I checked: changing stuff in GTK2 changed stuff in Kile. I couldn't find what value affected the "message log" area.

Comment: As far as QTconfig goes, I found that it seems like it doesn't touch font color.